# MySQL/MariaDB timestamp, datetime datatypes

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have created some tables with timestamp datatype. When I do a describe few timestamp columns show `current_timestamp` as default and few timestamp columns show `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000` as default. I thought timestamp column would only default to `current_timestamp`. I also understand that if we give those dates which are not in given range from documentation it will store the values as `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`. But how does it show different default value in the desc table output?

```
desc screen;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------------
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------------
| SCREEN_ID       | smallint(6)  | NO   | PRI | NULL
| SCREEN_NAME     | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL
| CREATED_BY      | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL
| CREATED_DATE    | timestamp(6) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
| UPDATED_BY      | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL
| UPDATED_DATE    | timestamp(6) | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
| SYSCREATED_DATE | timestamp(6) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
| SYSUPDATED_DATE | timestamp(6) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------------
```

Below is the DDL I used for table creation

```
CREATE TABLE SCREEN (
    SCREEN_ID SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    SCREEN_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
    CREATED_BY VARCHAR(30), 
    CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6), 
    UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(30), 
    UPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6), 
    SYSCREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    SYSUPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT SCREEN_PK PRIMARY KEY(SCREEN_ID)
);
```

Please help me. I am planning to change all the timestamp columns to datetime because of this discrepancy. Is it advisable?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `TIMESTAMP(6)` supposed to do?

Comment: I dint get your question. We are using these columns to store timestamp when a new row is inserted or an existing row is updated. It stores the timestamp value in this format 2015-08-03 19:49:43.187081

Comment: I'm wondering why you have `(6)` next to field type. Why would you cut off display length? There has to be a reason for that.

Comment: @Mhj timestamp(6) will store and show date in format YYMMDD. By the way, I'm not sure if OP really wanted this...

Comment: I am just using (6) to limit the precision of milli/micro seconds to 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATED_DATE` column has no default value. Therefore, describe shows some trash in default value column... Change it to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` like other fields.

Comment: Hi Jehy, Thanks a lot for your reply..I have not given any default value for created date as well as updated date...you can check the same in the DDL I posted earlier. So my question is why created_date shows current_timestamp where as updated_date show 0000-00...value when I describe the table

Comment: @user6404269 Oh, sorry, you did not describe what columns are questionable. For `created_date` and `updated_date` - there should be no difference. Try to modify your table to make columns same. By the way, I don't advice using TIMESTAMP type because it depends on server's timezone. Also see my comment at the question about timestamp(6).

Comment: Thank you Jehy, I have changed all the timestamp columns to datetime

Comment: @user6404269 It's my pleasure. You are welcome to mark this answer as a decision.